# ios update than WebView position bug showing

Tags: css-position, ios11

some body help me~~

## My Issue is this

IOS is Normal operation. but upgrade ios11 a bug broke out.

Scroll down quickly, My header menu hide, and scroll end than menu show.

My header is 'position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:50px;' had property.

Why does this happen?

i tried css edit and meta tag change...

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question has severe content and formatting problems and as such I believe is unsalvageable. Please read this before you post anything more on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

Application develop with cordova and using uiwebview on ios.

The css fixed elements have strange comportement : Hide, hide on scroll.
Try to look at this : https://ayogo.com/blog/ios11-viewport/

If it could fix

```
<meta name="viewport" content="..., viewport-fit=cover">
```